# COUNT in CASE statement?

Tags: mysql

I would like to categorize records based on the count of one field.
My code is :

```
 select `posts`.`post_customer_fs_id` AS `post_customer_fs_id`,count(`post_id`) AS `open_post_count`,
CASE count(`post_id`) 
WHEN count(`post_id`)=1 THEN 'A'
WHEN count(`post_id`)>1 THEN 'B'
END AS AAA
from `posts` where (`posts`.`post_status` = '3') AND posts.post_type_id='1' group by `posts`.`post_customer_fs_id` ;
```

For some reason I m receiving A for the records with COUNT 1 but NULL for the records with COUNT bigger than 1.
The post_id is an INTEGER field..
Any help it will be very appreciated!

Comment: On a sidenote: You don't actually need those ugly backticks; your names are fine without. Then, why do you compare status and type with '3' and '1'? Aren't these columns numeric? I'd expect `where post_status = 3 and post_type_id = 1` instead. At last there is no need to evaluate `post_id` in the count expression when you only want to count rows. Use `count(*)` instead.

Comment: Ok I will have these notes in mind too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
CASE count(post_id) 
  WHEN count(post_id)=1 THEN 'A'
```

You are comparing `count(post_id)` with `count(post_id)=1` where the latter results in true or false which equals 1 or 0 in MySQL. You want

```
CASE 
  WHEN count(post_id)=1 THEN 'A'
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you very much Thorsten! That was the problem! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

TRY :::

```
select post_customer_fs_id AS 'post_customer_fs_id', count(post_id) AS 'open_post_count',
CASE 
    WHEN count(post_id)=1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN count(post_id)>1 THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'C'
END AS 'AAA'
from posts where post_status = '3' AND post_type_id= '1' 
group by post_customer_fs_id ;
```

Comment: Hello Prince! Unfortunatelly it doesn't work that way. Thanx anyway!